# Google Japanese Input/Simeji warning about inserted data

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, input-methods

I've recently bought a Samsung Galaxy Pocket with Gingerbread (Android 2.3).

I expected Japanese not to be there as an input method, although Korean *is* there (why Korean and not Japanese and Chinese?), and anyway, I looked for apps that allowed me to type Japanese.

I found Google Japanese Input and Simeji. Both look wonderful... in the screenshots. I haven't tried any yet. The reason is that every time I try to turn them on, a warning appears that says (translated from italian):

> Attention: this input method can gather all digited text, including password, credit card numbers and other personal data. Continue?

I didn't accept, but this means I cannot type Japanese. What is the exact meaning of this warning? I mean, other than the literal meaning that I can understand. Why should it take my credit card number, if and when I type it? Or my passwords? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it's saying that the app could potentially steal your information, as it's a keyboard and therefore processes what you type. For instance, if you typed your password in and it was malicious, it could *potentially* record that (and everything else you type). Of course, you could trust Google wouldn't do that...Android is simply reminding you of the risk.

Further reading: [The FAQ for the Hacker's Keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_is_there_a_security_warning_when_I_activate_it?)

The warning can be found in the [Android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/8272edba7d10b508cbbedfce5504862da6ec9acd/res/values/strings.xml) (see line ~2687).

Comment: Is there any official document (like a FAQ or something similar) that I could consult about this? I couldn't find anything, except general FAQ or similar things.

Comment: Researching, I found a disclaimer in another app that said that the "collecting data warning" is standard on 3rd party apps on Android.

Comment: @Alenanno: see http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_is_there_a_security_warning_when_I_activate_it? and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/8272edba7d10b508cbbedfce5504862da6ec9acd/res/values/strings.xml line 2687.

Comment: Great thanks. Maybe you could add that to the answer so other people see it (in case comments get deleted in the future). :D